# Remove a column from Jtable and rearrange it

Tags: java, jtable

I have JComboBox to select Designation. and I have JTable it's columns are EmpId,Name,Status,Start Time,End Time. When I select designation "Clerk"
JTable should appears with only EmpId,Name,Status If I select designation as "Labourer" JTable should appears with EmpId,Name,Status,Start Time,End Time columns. I did thi but it gives a error,

jTable1.removeColumn(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));
jTable1.removeColumn(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4));

Then only  EmpId,Name,Status,End Time appears and It gave arrayoutofboundsexception

what is the mistake here

and also I need to get those Columns(3 and 4(Start time, End time Columns)) again to display when I select designation "Clerk"
so I used this code but it's not giving required output

```
String desig=cmbAtSelectDesig.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(desig.contentEquals("Clerk")){
 jTable3.addColumn(jTable3.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));
           jTable3.addColumn(jTable3.getColumnModel().getColumn(4));
}
   What is the mistake here Please Give me a solution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) object from the middle of array, it removes [TableColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html) that renders this column, thus current array that hold all columns will be "PRIOR size -1", so the one that is on the right (the last one) will move to the left, you "End Time" position is now at "3 ", to avoid this problem, don't even think about deleting twice  3rd column, it's unprofessional and messy, simply start deleting from the end of the array,  4  ----> 3

Updated:

first of all i never used JTABLE before, almost for sure what i'm doing is an embarrassment to all JAVA community, never the less...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class Tester {
    JFrame frane;
    JPanel mainP;
    JTable table;
    public void testIt() {
        frane=new JFrame("testing");
        populateGui();
        frane.setContentPane(mainP);
        frane.pack();
        frane.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frane.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void populateGui() {
        mainP=new JPanel();
        String[] colName={"first col","second","3rd coll"};
        String[][] information={
                    {"DUCK","QUACK","MacDuck"}
                };
        table=new JTable(information, colName);
        table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));
        System.out.println(table.
                getColumnModel().
                    getColumnCount()
        );
        System.out.println(table.
                getModel().
                    getColumnCount()
        );
        table=new JTable(table.getModel());  // yet all the data object that were present in data array () "information" are still there
        /*table.addColumn(
                table.getColumnModel().          there is no column 2 since it was removed from ColumRendere (ColumnModel)
                    getColumn(2));*/
        mainP.add(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you have mentioned it gave the output.But It gives this error.   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 3 What is the problem here

Comment: and also I need to get those Columns(3 and 4(Start time, End time Columns)) again to display when I select designation "Clerk"
so I used this code but it's not giving required output

 

    String desig=cmbAtSelectDesig.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(desig.contentEquals("Clerk")){
     jTable3.addColumn(jTable3.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));
               jTable3.addColumn(jTable3.getColumnModel().getColumn(4));
    }
       What is the mistake here Please Give me a solution

Comment: I did this then when I select cleark(All the columns present) then when i select Labourer none of the columns were present here is my code jPanelAttendance.add(jTableAttendance); i'm a beginner so there might be have some mistakes Please guide me

Comment: although you have a working example in front of you, you still want someone to guide you, it's about time you consider to change your qualification. Also google  [link](https://www.google.it/?gws_rd=ssl#q=SSCCE+) it. To resolve any problem it's essential to what is your problem.

Comment: I could only wonder that you somewhere lost the reference to something, thus it use as default NULL. If it happens due to instantiation of new table, which will cut the reference to the table present in GUI, that you can try to reuse old reference  "table.setColumnModel(new JTable(table.getModel()).getColumnModel())".

Comment: also take  a look at [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponent%28int%29) and  [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29) You have  showed zero effort and complete ignorance in a matter of heap, stack, object reference, lifespan. Thus if you still need any help make a new question following SSCCE [link](http://sscce.org/)